# Using Select inside INSERT INTO table

Tags: sql, insert

I never tried this and I don't know if it's wrong.

```
INSERT INTO produits(produit_id, fournisseur_id, marque_id, categorie_id,produit_nom,
                     produit_prix, produit_description, quantite_stock,
                     date_production, date_expiration)
    VALUES (seq_produits.nextval,
            SELECT fournisseur_id FROM fournisseurs WHERE fournisseur_nom='LebanoCop',
            SELECT marque_id FROM marques WHERE marque_nom='Hyper-Products',
            SELECT categorie_id FROM categories WHERE categorie_nom='viandes',
            'Mortadella', 2000, 'tres delicieuse', 100, '25-MAY-2012', '25-MAY-2013')
```

Can this work? I am getting error that there's missing expression. I'm using Oracle.

Comment: Remove the "VALUES" keyword: INSERT INTO produits(...) SELECT seq_produits.nextval, fournisseur_id, ... FROM ..  Make sure the number of entries in your SELECT list matches the number in your INSERT list.

Comment: Are all the `SELECT` statements guaranteed to return at most one row?

Comment: Put subqueries in parentheses - that is, if answer to Martin Smiths' question is yes, and by the names used in query it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want three selected values that will be singleton results from each of three sub-queries.  I believe the notation that should work is:

```
INSERT INTO produits(produit_id, fournisseur_id, marque_id, categorie_id,produit_nom,
                     produit_prix, produit_description, quantite_stock,
                     date_production, date_expiration)
   VALUES (seq_produits.nextval,
           (SELECT fournisseur_id FROM fournisseurs WHERE fournisseur_nom='LebanoCop'),
           (SELECT marque_id FROM marques WHERE marque_nom='Hyper-Products'),
           (SELECT categorie_id FROM categories WHERE categorie_nom='viandes'),
           'Mortadella', 2000, 'tres delicieuse', 100, '25-MAY-2012', '25-MAY-2013')
```

There is an extra set of parentheses required around each sub-query compared to your original SQL.  This avoids any issues with joining unjoinable result sets.

In the general case, where you are trying to select a possibly large number of rows to insert, you would not use the VALUES clause at all and would simply list the SELECT statement after the INSERT column list:

```
INSERT INTO produits(produit_id, ...)
    SELECT ...
```